# Android Test module cannot find file in assets directory

Tags: android, unit-testing

In Android Studio (v0.4.4), I have a project with 2 modules, one for the app code, the other for the testing code.  The app module is an Android Library project and the test module was created as an Android Application.

My unit test, which extends `InstrumentationTestCase`, attempts to read test data from an XML file stored in `src/main/assets/sample.xml` of the test module.  However, I continue to receive `FileNotFoundException` errors when opening the file (second line below).

```
AssetManager assetMgr = this.getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets();
InputStream stream = assetMgr.open("sample.xml");
```

When I try to list the contents of the `assets` directory, the `String[]` returned from `assetMgr.list()` is empty.

Other unit tests in the same test module, which *do not* read this same test data, execute fine and succeed.

Why can't this one unit test read a file from it's own assets directory?

Thank you!

Comment: You should have used ```getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()``` instead of ```getInstrumentation().getContext()```.